# Geodesic circle on a pseudosphere

Tags: export, geometry

I am trying to 3D print a portion of the pseudosphere, whose edge is geodesic circle. To do so, I plotted a region of the pseudosphere with the geodesics emanating from a point and I got this:
[image: Region of a pseudosphere with geodesics emanating from a point]

The surface is parametrised by three functions of two parameters whereas the geodesics are obtained by numerical integration of the geodesic equations as x(t),y(t) and z(t) via the parametric nd solver of mathematical. The parameter (c) regulates the starting angle of the geodesic.

I am trying now to extract a .stl file but I need to "cut" the orange surface that is not reached by the geodesics. Do you guys know a way to do that?

In this picture you can see how the geodesic circle looks like:
[image]

Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: Can you add the code you used to generate the graphic and the code you used to export to STL? I think you just want to clip out a circular region correct?

Comment: Yes but in this case I don't get a geodesic circle right? So I am looking for a way of taking advantage of the geodesics. Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: @MatteoPezzulla. If you need to merge accounts (I'm assuming the two Matteo's here are one and the same), please contact the moderators.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use the `RegionFunction` option here?

```
Plot3D[
  x^2 - y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 16]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 16, {x, y}], {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#^2 + #2^2 &, # &, #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{16}, 10, 10}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#^2 + #2^2 &}, Mesh -> {{16}}, 
 MeshShading -> { Automatic, None}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE]wAb.jpg